# Any remaining Appcelerator Titanium problems with XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I'm wondering whether Titanium truly works 100% with XCode 4? Can anyone confirm that *they've personally upgraded to XCode 4, and have been able to build apps*?

I realize that this is supposed to work, but I've seen conflicting posts about it in the Appcelerator forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had trouble with it, in fact I've had to use Xcode 4 rather then Titanium Developer to get some custom barcode scanning modules to work.